# Azure App Service - What does Client Certificate Mode Allow or Optional actually do?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

For an Azure App Service if you set `Client Certificate Mode` to `Require` then the App Service (technically the Azure load balancer) performs an mTLS handshake. As shown in the following WireShark trace showing the `Certicate Request` from the server followed by the `Certificate` response from the client.

[image]

If however `Client Certificate Mode` is set to `Allow` or `Optional`, and also with `Require` if you have any `Certificate exclusion paths` set, then this handshake does not appear to occur, although strangely, the client certificate is still presented to the App Service via the `X-ARR-ClientCert` request header.

The concern I have is that the mTLS handshake is what establishes that the client has the private key to the certificate. If in `Allow` or `Optional` mode the certificate is forwarded to the App Service without this handshake having taken place, does that mean the App Service is potentially being presented with a client certificate that client might not even have the private key to, which would be really bad, or is this handshake check being done somewhere else behind the scenes?

The Azure documentation around this is non-existant.

Comment: When u force the mTLS to be at the TLS handshake stage, you are avoiding large Post/Put issues see this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/https-client-certificate-request-freezes-when-the-server-is/ba-p/339672

Comment: I haven't verified this, but agree this is poorly documented and a worry. Given that TLS handshaking occurs before HTTP information is available to the server, the only way to validate a client certificate with "certificate exclusion paths" in place is to force TLS renegotiation, which comes with a [range of problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0#optional-client-certificates).  If that's the intention, it should at least be documented, but the MS docs so far only address validating certificate properties/trust.